# extended permission for fan page

Tags: facebook

i made a fan page application and now i want to show user images or his/her album from facebook in that page.But for this , i have to ask permission.But don't know how to ask extended permission on the fan page.Is there any way to ask permission in fan page..?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An App running on a page tab operates like any other app, you can prompt the user via the [standard authentication methods](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Hust make sure to request the `user_photos` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) and then you'll be able to retrieve a list of their photos via the API